# Continuous Image Marquee in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I need Continuous Image marquee in HTML in horizontal direction. I got the code for text marquee it is working , but not for images. Thanks in advance.

Continuous text marquee link: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=28742

Comment: No offense intended, but, image marquee? I really don't like even the sound of it.

Comment: 1990 called, they want their marquee back!

Comment: I want to flag this as offensive...

Comment: Are you even loading the images properly? What's in your version of the code?

Answer (score 2):

1- Do not use marquee.

2- ?

3- Profit !

If you really have to, try to use a [jQuery alternative](http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html) or [another kind of UI](http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/)

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask what for?

I would suggest against using the marquee all together, it's extremely dated and in my opinion looks tacky. I'm pretty sure you can't use it for images either.

If you want scrolling images I would point you in the direction of JQuery. Maybe something like this would be better: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/